# Update a UIVIew again and again and again

Tags: iphone, uiview

I'm making a simple iPhone app whose sole function is to update a UIView forever (until it exits).

I tried this in applicationDidFinishLaunching and viewDidLoad:

```
while(1) {  
    // update view here  
}
```

but that doesn't work- the app never finishes loading. I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, I just don't know what it its.

Also: ideally, this process should consume very little resources.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the `UIView`? Update its contents? Its position?

Comment: Background color- I'm making an app which generates color schemes .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have a `while (1)` statement like there, as it not allow viewDidLoad to return, and your app will never get any other calls such as tap processing, screen draw updates, etc.

In viewDidLoad, set up a timer task using:

```
updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: kUpdateTimeInterval target:self selector:@selector(updateView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And have a method called `updateView` that actually does the updating.  Instead of `updateView` you could also use `setNeedsDisplay` which will trigger a call the -drawRect method of your view class, and do the actual drawing there.

What ends up happening now is that your viewDidLoad will set up a repeating task and at every kUpdateInterval, your view will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the view all the time, maybe you could just call its -setNeedsDisplay method when the data that you're displaying changes.