# Updating UIView after some time interval?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit

I want to create Custom Views that call webservice after some time and update themself..The data should be updated even when the application is not in active state.. so What is the best way for doing this ??

Comment: Have you tried any solutions yourself?

Comment: try this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552080/update-a-uiview-again-and-again-and-again

Comment: @MarcinKuptel l  have already worked with NSTimer.. but as i said i want to update the data even the application is in the background..and i have no idea of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `NSTimer` for that. Add your code in your custom method and call that method like bellow..

```
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f target:self selector:@selector(yourMethodName:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Here in `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` Parameter you can set the time in seconds so your method which passes in `selector` Parameter is called after every 3 seconds..

See one Example and tutorial of `NSTimer` From this link [nstimer-tutorial-creating-clockstopwatchtimer-iphoneipad](http://www.ioslearner.com/nstimer-tutorial-creating-clockstopwatchtimer-iphoneipad/)

**UPDATE:**

If you want to call webservice then you can use `NSThread` like bellow...

```
- (void) runTimer 
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateAllVisibleElements)toTarget:self withObject:nil]; 
}

- (void) updateAllVisibleElements  {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    if(service == nil)
    {
        service = [[WebService alloc] init];
    }
    [service getlocationID:currentLatitude andlongitude:currentLongitute];
    [pool release];
}
```

See the link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665192/how-to-call-json-webservice-from-background-in-iphone)

Comment: can you call webservice in background  ? in question he also mention that call the webservice in background also

Comment: No No For that you can see the answer and que here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665192/how-to-call-json-webservice-from-background-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSTimer`, but data will not update when application is in background mode. After application became active `NSTimer` will continue working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to track the location, but you'll not be able to connect to your web-services when the app is in the background.